# Error while trying sending mail across gmail using logback and spring boot

Tags: java, spring, email, spring-boot, logback

I am using spring boot : 1.4.0. With the following configuration in logback,I am trying to send a mail to gmail.

```
<appender name="EMAIL" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender">
    <smtpHost>smtp.gmail.com</smtpHost>
    <smtpPort>25</smtpPort>
    <SSL>true</SSL>
    <username>*</username>
    <password>*</password>

    <to>*</to>
    <from>*</from>
    <subject>TESTING: %logger{20} - %m</subject>
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <pattern>%date %-5level %logger{35} - %message%n</pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>

<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="EMAIL" />
</root>
```

But getting the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedBasicPropertyIA - Unexpected aggregationType AS_BASIC_PROPERTY_COLLECTION
at       org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:152)
at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.reinitialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:195)
at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:65)
at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:50)
at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:106)
at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:289)
at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:262)
at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:231)
at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:207)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:166)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:121)
at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:68)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:336)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1182)
```

Main program Spring Boot

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("log.name", "dynamicLogs");
    logger.debug("Start running debug");
    SpringApplication.run(WebApplication.class, args);
    logger.error("Start running error");            
}
```

. **While if i try to run a test java program it runs fine. Not sure what the issue is while running with spring boot.Missing any properties to be set?**

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with logback version 1.1.7. Spring Boot 1.3.4 and 1.3.5 depend on this version, so 1.4.0 might also.

You can try forcing an older/newer version of logback.

More information in https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder/issues/160

Comment: Tried using older version,didn't helped. I doubt I am missing some properties to be configured in logback.

Comment: You can try to remove some properties. I had problems with a property that logback didn't understand, after removing that property it also worked.

Comment: I think these are bare minimum that I have used.

Answer (score 1):

You are encountering issue with the `to` field. See [THIS](http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-1158) bug report. You will have to wait for 1.1.8 or downgrade to version 1.1.6.
With Spring Boot you can just do the following

```
<properties>
    <logback.version>1.1.6</logback.version> 
</properties>
```